# Convert Map with list values to list of tuples

Tags: scala

I have a `Map[String,List[String]]` and I would like to have this converted to a `List[(String, String)]` where the first element of a given `Tuple` is a map key and the second element is a member of the corresponding list from the map.

For example:

```
Map[String,List[String]](
  "a" -> List("aa", "ab", "ac"),
  "b" -> List("ba", "bb")
)
```

Should become:

```
List((a,aa), (a,ab), (a,ac), (b,ba), (b,bb))
```

What I do currently is this, you can find a demo [here](http://ideone.com/j5FRoA):

```
(for{
  tuple <- mapOfLists
}yield{
  tuple._2.map{ elem =>
    (tuple._1,elem)
  }
}).toList.flatten
```

It works just fine but I think could be done better, is there a completely functional way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 mapOfLists.toList.flatMap({case (k, l) => l.map((k, _))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension with a simpler yield, like this

```
for ( (k,l) <- mapOfLists.toList ; v <- l ) yield (k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

val result: List[(String, String)] = 
   mapOfLists.flatMap({ case (k, l) => l.map(k -> _) })(breakOut)
```

This way no intermediate list is created - `flatMap` will create the resulting list directly. But you need to put `flatMap` call into a context where a correct type can be inferred, like variable assignment with explicit type.